# Дуб и лопух

Tags: этимология

Почему тугодумов называют "дуб" — это понятно. Вроде как он такой же твердолобый. Но почему разинь называют "лопухами"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лопоухий: развесил уши.

Answer (score 1):

Лопух к ушам не имеет никакого отношения. Слово правславянского происхождения, от морфа со значением - широкий, просторный. Родственно "листу" и "лопате".

Что касается лопухов двуногих, то некая связь с лопоухостью если и возможна, то скорее - в обратном направлении. Лопоухих стали называть по созвучию с лопухами. 
А значение, видимо, связано с кажущейся простой и открытостью лопуха (хотя на самом деле это очень интресное растение).

Comment: Присоединяюсь к этому мнению

Answer (score 1):

Вырез у рубахи, плотно прилегал к шее. Разиня это человек по забывчивости (рассеяности ) пытающийся стянуть застёгнутую  рубаху , через голову . Естественно уши от такого эксперимента- краснели .Как гребень петуха.

Answer (score 0):

Лопух, потому что съедобный, это о растении.

"У лопухов можно использовать в пищу корни, которые богаты инулином. Сочные нежные корни собирают осенью первого года жизни растения. Мука из высушенных корней лопуха, смешанная с двойным количеством ржаной муки, может служить для выпечки хлеба, поджаренный корень — для примеси к кофе. Рекомендуют ещё варить тонко измельчённый корень с кислым молоком, щавелём, уксусом для превращения инулина в очень сладкий сахар (левулёзу)[8]. В пищу используют также молодые побеги. Большие листья тоже съедобны, но невкусны.
Медонос[9]"
Лекарственное растение.

Лопать можно, и лист похож на ухо. Конкатенация смысловая. Объединение двух слов в одно.

Оспаривать можно,  но при этом корень ух надо как-то иначе озвучить в смысловом плане.
Например "есть это, ух, как можно" в виде междометия.
Можно разбить слово на два слога, ло и пух, пояснив смысловое значение каждого, связь данных слогов.
А можно и найти "морф"- широкий, но еще и надо обозначить ссылкой на источник, откуда это взялось.

Еще лопух называют репейником, чертополохом.  Вот это поинтересней.

Скорее лопоухий от лопуха, а Лопух в смысле:  лох, дурак, идиот  - вот это точно:  "уши развесил". На уговоры-лесть, и все что связано с надувательством--как раз то самое определение. 
Лопата и лопотать, куда ближе к слову лопать, то есть характерного звука, издаваемого языком, лоп. Оттуда и лепетать, лопочет, хлоп, ЛОПАТА.
 Оттуда же и поговорка: "Гребет языком, как лопатой"